# I want to run my own interface that I coded with Python in RoboDK

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, plugins, settings

I want to add a button to RoboDK and I want my interface to work when I click on this button. How can I do it?

What I am waiting for;
Adding a button to RoboDK and adding my own logo to this button. Then when I press this button, my code works.